# installing rails 2.0.0-p353 error on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I am currently running Ubuntu 13.10, rvm 1.24.8, and rails 4.0.2. I currently have a working version of ruby 1.9.3-p448. I'm trying to install the current version of ruby 2.0.0-p353 but I am currently getting errors installing the gems.

---

```
    Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
    No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/13.10/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p353.
    Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
    Checking requirements for rvm_pkg.

    Warning, you are using 'rvm autolibs rvm_pkg', this is rarely used and can produce errors,
    make sure to report any problems to https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

    Requirements installation successful.
    Installing Ruby from source to: /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
    ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p353, this may take a while depending on your connection...
    ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p353 to /home/brian/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p353.
    ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #extracted to /home/brian/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p353
    ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #configuring.................................................
    ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #post-configuration.
    ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #compiling.............................................................................
    ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #installing.............................
    Retrieving rubygems-2.1.11
    Extracting rubygems-2.1.11 ....
    Removing old Rubygems files...
    Installing rubygems-2.1.11 for ruby-2.0.0-p353..
    Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/home/brian        /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global:/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global GEM_HOME=/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353 /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -d /home/brian/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/setup.rb',
    showing last 15 lines of /home/brian/.rvm/log/1387299251_ruby-2.0.0-p353/rubygems.install.log
    [2013-12-17 11:56:44] /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
    current path: /home/brian/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11
    command(6): env GEM_PATH=/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global:/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global GEM_HOME=/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353 /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -d /home/brian/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/setup.rb
    Exception `LoadError' at /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1087 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
    Exception `LoadError' at /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1096 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
    /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 8 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
from /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
from /home/brian/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:332:in `load_file'
from /home/brian/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
from /home/brian/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
from /home/brian/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
from /home/brian/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
from setup.rb:45:in `<main>'
    Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
    Saving wrappers to '/home/brian/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353'...
    .
    ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
    ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #importing default gemsets, this may take time.......
    Install of ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #complete 
    Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
```

so anyone have any ideas what's going on? And thanks for helping!

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353

Comment: Do first `rvm get stable` then `rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353`.

Comment: yes I already did that

Comment: i guess i'll stick with 1.9.3 might as well not fix anything this isn't broken

Answer (score 0):

it is a bug in either `~/.gemrc` or `/etc/gemrc` check `line 8 column 1`